# Is there anyway to make a certain project in a solution Readonly in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I currently have multiple projects inside a solution in VS2010. Sometimes while working on one project inside the solution I need to look at some files from a different solution. However I am always afraid that I might make some accidental changes to the project that I am only referring to. Is there any way to make a project readonly inside a solution in VS2010 ?

Comment: I don't know of any way to make a project readonly. But if you used a version control system (like SVN or Git), it would be very easy to revert unintended changes. Even hobbyist developers should use a version control system.

Comment: You could make the project folder readonly, using Explorer, before opening it in VS2010.  Signed, Captain Obvious   :-)   Clearly this is a clumsy solution.

Comment: How about opening the other solution in a separate instance of VS2010?  You could still mess up, but it would be harder.  

Another idea: There doesn't appear to be any "Open as ReadOnly" option.  But there is an "Open with..." option.  So you could use a different editor to open the files that you just want to consult.  Again, not foolproof, but might make it harder to mess up.

Comment: One last idea: Make ALL your VS files readonly.  Then use the trick described in web page below, which allows VS to write to readonly files, AFTER GIVING YOU A WARNING and OBTAINING THE GO-AHEAD.  If you say "go ahead," VB removes the readonly attribute, and does the save.  So you'd have to re-set the readonly attribute afterward.  Not a problem for the project you're currently working on.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/15/edit-read-only-files-vstipedit0074.aspx